# How to use a function returning a tuple to add multiple columns to data frame in Polars

Tags: python-polars

I have a dataframe with a single column:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a':[1,2,3,4]
})
print(df)

shape: (4, 1)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 1   │
│ 2   │
│ 3   │
│ 4   │
└─────┘
```

And a function from int to (int, int):

```py
def f(i): return (i*10, i*100)
```

I want to use `f` to add 2 columns `b,c` to the data frame. In the process I want to explicitly set the datatype for those 2 columns (in reality they are not ints, could be a Polars struct, array, etc.)

I tried:

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col('a').apply(f).alias('temp'))
```

But can't get this to work in general as `f` is returning a tuple of complex dtypes.

Desired result:

```py
print(out)

shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 100 │
│ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ 200 │
│ 3   ┆ 30  ┆ 300 │
│ 4   ┆ 40  ┆ 400 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Are you in control of the function? You can return a `dict` instead which will give you a struct you can `.unnest()` - alternatively you can `list.to_struct()`

Comment: Thanks! That moved me forward a bit. Would you mind fleshing both `unnest` and `to_struct` out, assuming I want the 'b' column to be (say) Int32, and the 'c' column to be (say) Struct('val': Int64)?

Comment: Python dicts are turned into structs. So if you return: `dict(b=10, c=dict(val=20))` for example you should get what you're describing. [`Dataframe.unnest()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest) creates new columns from structs.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as asked you can do this:

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(pl.col('a').apply(f).alias('temp'))
    .with_columns(pl.col('temp').list.to_struct(fields=['b','c']))
    .unnest('temp')
    .with_columns(pl.col('b','c').cast(pl.Int32()))
)
```

You can't chain the `list.to_struct` in the same `with_columns` as the apply. I think it has to do with apply looping on each element so it isn't, for lack of a better term, a fully formed column yet. If you want the output to be a specific dtype, you have to cast it after you unnest.

That being said, **using apply is an anti-pattern** and should be avoided wherever possible as it undoes all of the optimizations that make polars fast. Ideally you'd convert your `f` into polars expressions. If there's no way to make `f` into polars expressions but it can be vectorized then use `map` instead of `apply`.